# dnvm upgrade failing with exception

Tags: dnvm, asp.net5, .net-core-rc1

I'm getting an unhelpful exception when running `dnvm upgrade`:

```
C:\Users\...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\foo>dnvm upgrade
Determining latest version
Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!
At C:\Users\banksd\.dnx\bin\dnvm.ps1:483 char:9
+         throw "Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to find ...es on the feed!:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!
```

I also can't resolve `"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"` in a fresh ASP.NET 5 project.

Don't know if the two are related.

Any advise?

Comment: Are you on RC2, if so `dnvm` is gone?

Comment: Maybe not...  I'll upgrade.

Comment: @DavidPine I think I must be as I'm using VS 2015 Update 2.  How can I confirm it though?

Comment: walk up to a command line and try `dotnet --version`

Comment: Also see :: http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html

Comment: @DavidPine Cheers, I don't seem to have an executable called `dotnet.exe` anywhere on my hard drive though.  I guess I need to uninstall the old ASP.NET version manually?

Comment: Yes, follow the migration guide -- and you will need to upgrade a lot of other things as well.

Comment: Replaced the tags, so that such question won't pollute .NET Core tags. All RC1 related questions/answers should not contain ".net-core" nor "asp.net-core" IMHO.